# showing data in textboxes using access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

ave a table namely studentsrecords which consists of IDNumber,Firstname,Lastname,MiddleName and Course

I will login the system with my IDNumber as my username and MiddleName to be my password

it will direct me to the form that has 3 textboxes.: txtIDNumber,txtLastName and txtCourse

all i want is when i log in the system with my IDNumber.,.,it will load data in textboxes the IDNumber which i use to log in, The lastname of the students IDNumber and the Course of the student,.,using IDNumber 
im only a newbie here..

con.Open()

```
   Dim str As String = "SELECT * FROM studentsrecords"

   Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(str, con)

   da = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)

   ds = New DataSet

   con.Open()

   da.Fill(ds, "evaluation")

   con.Close()

   txtflash.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds.Tables("evaluation"), "LastName")

   txtcourse.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds.Tables("evaluation"), "Course")
```

Answer (score 0):

1st You have to send IdNumber to MainForm from login form and set your query as,

```
Dim str As String = "SELECT * FROM studentsrecords where IDNumber=[Id Number from Login Form] "
```

Then,

Please try like this,

```
txtflash.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", ds.Tables("evaluation"), "LastName"))

txtcourse.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", ds.Tables("evaluation"), "Course"))
```

Comment: No value given for one or more required parameters.

da.Fill(ds, "evaluation")

Comment: In his example above, where he wrote "[Id Number from Login Form]", you need to put the criteria to get the single record from the StudentRecords table.